# how to integrate my kotlin application with console/terminal

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, console, console-application

can we integrate console (cmd,powershell) into an android application??, if we can how can one proceed to such thing.....

by integrate i mean to say that we pass some commands through our application and the commands will run in the console (this all should work on my phone not my laptop/pc..like if we use mkdir command this should create a directory in my phone)

is such a thing possible if yes then how?

i tried searching for it but cannot seem to find a specific solution or steps for this problem